# How To Login The Website With PYTHON Requests and Scrape

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Guys i know too many people ask of it but i even try it myself too much thing.
But i cant figure out

I can't log in on this web site : "http://erp.unitecmakina.com/login.aspx"

i tried

```
"payload = {
    "popAnaEkran$Kul_GirisAd": "id",
    "popAnaEkran$Kul_GirisSifre": "passaword"
}

session_requests = requests.session()
login_url = "http://erp.unitecmakina.com/dashboard"
result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data = payload,
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a .aspx website (ASP.net) which are fairly difficult to do with requests. I highly suggest something like Selenium. Here is why. Looking at the Developer Console. The POST request to login requires a lot of form data (see below). It would take a lot of work to reverse all that form data.

```
__EVENTTARGET: 
__EVENTARGUMENT: 
__VIEWSTATE: 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
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: C2EE9ABB
popAnaEkranState: {&quot;windowsState&quot;:&quot;1:1:12002:471:483:0:-10000:-10000:1:0:0:0&quot;}
popAnaEkran$Kul_GirisAd$State: {&quot;rawValue&quot;:&quot;asdfasdf&quot;,&quot;validationState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
popAnaEkran$Kul_GirisAd: asdfasdf
popAnaEkran$Kul_GirisSifre$State: {&quot;rawValue&quot;:&quot;asdfasdf&quot;,&quot;validationState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
popAnaEkran$Kul_GirisSifre: asdfasdf
popAnaEkran$btnGiris: Giriş
popHataState: {&quot;windowsState&quot;:&quot;1:1:12000:274:70:0:-10000:-10000:1:0:0:0&quot;}
popLisansState: {&quot;windowsState&quot;:&quot;0:0:-1:0:0:0:-10000:-10000:1:0:0:0&quot;}
popLisans_LisYer_VI: 
popLisans$LisYer: 
popLisans$LisYer$DDDState: {&quot;windowsState&quot;:&quot;0:0:-1:0:0:0:-10000:-10000:1:0:0:0&quot;}
popLisans$LisYer$DDD$L$State: {&quot;CustomCallback&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
popLisans$LisYer$DDD$L: 
popLisans$cbpLisans$LisAktivasyon: 
popLisans$LisAkTarih: 
popLisans$LisSurumu: 4.13.3.18
popGuncellemeState: {&quot;windowsState&quot;:&quot;0:0:-1:0:0:0:-10000:-10000:1:0:0:0&quot;}
popSifreState: {&quot;windowsState&quot;:&quot;0:0:-1:0:0:0:-10000:-10000:1:0:0:0&quot;}
popSifre$Sfr_GirisAd: 
popSifirlaState: {&quot;windowsState&quot;:&quot;0:0:-1:0:0:0:-10000:-10000:1:0:0:0&quot;}
popSifirla$Sfr_Sifre1: 
popSifirla$Sfr_Sifre2: 
EkranEn: 3840
EkranBoy: 2160
DXScript: 1_233,1_135,1_226,1_169,1_132,1_218,1_216,1_167,1_175,1_156,1_174,1_139,1_180,1_166,1_164,1_170,1_215,1_134
DXCss: 1_33,1_18,1_16,1_17,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Web/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Web/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Editors/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Editors/sprite.css,images/Crm.ico,Script_CSS/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Chart/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/GridView/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/GridView/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/HtmlEditor/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/HtmlEditor/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/PivotGrid/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/PivotGrid/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Scheduler/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Scheduler/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/SpellChecker/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Spreadsheet/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Spreadsheet/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/TreeList/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/TreeList/styles.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Web/DocumentViewerSprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Web/HESprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Web/RESprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/Web/SSSprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/XtraReports/sprite.css,App_Themes/CrmTheme/XtraReports/styles.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Most sites require cookies, make a get request to the homepage of the site and then access the cookies by doing r.cookies , and some sites have csrf tokens or some sort of token system in the html (it can also be stored in a cookie) all sites require headers, open chrome and go to the network tab and look at the post request made when you login , look at the request headers, you can copy those and put them in a dictionary , you can also get rid of the session